# Values in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

Below is a working example that I found online, looking to use something very similar.

How do you get 2 different prices and currencies to display from the drop list for the same selection, without making multiple drop downs for each currency/price?
from what I've been told you can only save the Value from a drop down to mysql (the price value in this scenario) I would like to save the selected name instead of the currency/price.. or even both if that's possible?

```
<select id="bedrooms" onchange="changeddl(this)">
          <option>Choose beds</option>
          <option value="150">1 bed</option>
          <option value="200">2 beds</option>
          <option value="300">3 beds</option>
          <option value="400">4 beds</option>
        </select>

        <div id="divprice"></div>

        function changeddl($this){
           $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?("price: $ " + $this.value):"");
        };
```

Comment: you could use data attributes if you are not bothered about actually submitting the data other wise you would need a delimited value and do a split on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for displaying the name as well as the price

`function changeddl($this){
           var item = $('#bedrooms option:selected').text()
           $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?(item +"- price: $ " + $this.value):"");
        };`

as for selecting currency, i would suggest you to use a different dropdown which lets the user select the preferred currency

Comment: Hi Omkar,

do you perhaps have an example of how I would go about doing the currency selector... I only need the currency to display in USD and in RANDS (ZAR)..(both at the same time when drop down selected would be nice)

All i really need is a dropdown list.. it lists the items.. user selectes item.. it shows price in USD and in RANDS .. after he fills in rest of form (username/email etc) hits submit .. it writes to my db.. but i dont want the price of the item written to db.. i only want the item name so that i know this is what the user selected

Comment: @NealFourie  .. for displaying currency in USD and Rand, you could use similar code and make use of a formula involving currency conversion of USD to Rand.. keep the base price in USD and apply the conversion formula on that price.. for example 
value 1 in dropdown is 150, take it as 150 USD and apply conversion formula 1USD = 12.27Rand .. you can use something like this
`function changeddl($this){
  var item = $('#bedrooms option:selected').text()
   $("#divprice").text($this.value>0?(item +"- price: $ " + $this.value + " Rand " + (parseInt($this.value) * 12.27)):"");
  };`
i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Omkar, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a drop down list? Then you can use a trim function to set a variable equal to the user's selection in the drop down. Here is an example:

```
<td><asp:DropDownList ID ="BedroomsDropDown" runat="server" Width="75px"
                        >
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>$150, 1 bed</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>$200, 2 beds</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>$300, 3 beds</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>$400, 4 beds</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
```

Then you can save the user input into a variable with:

```
BEDS = BedroomsDropDown.Text.Trim();
```

Just be sure to save the user input using a method that is called by another action (a button works well). I can provide example code for this if needed. When the input is saved into a variable it can be manipulated for whatever purposes you need.